# An image of my server for use with Vagrant?

Tags: vagrant

Is it possible to build a box for vagrant from a real box?

I have inherited some CentOS servers I'd like to use as base boxes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a tool like [virt-p2v](http://libguestfs.org/virt-v2v/) or [vcenter converter](http://www.vmware.com/products/converter/) to create a virtual disk image which you can attach to a virtual machine in virtualbox. Then you just need to follow the steps to [create a base box](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/virtualbox/boxes.html).